# Slicing a nested hash in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, slice

Say I have a hash that I can index as:

```
$hash{$document}{$word}
```

From what I read online (although I could not find this on [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#Access-and-Printing-of-a-HASH-OF-ARRAYS) or [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Slices)), I can slice a hash using a list if I use the `@` prefix on my hash to indicate that I want the hash to return a list. However, if I try to slice my hash using a list `@list`:

```
@%hash{$document}{@list}
```

I get several `"Scalar values ... better written"`  errors.

How can I slash a nested hash in Perl?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The sigill for your hash must be `@`, like so:

```
@{$hash{$document}}{@list}
```

Assuming `@list` contains valid keys for `%hash` it will return the corresponding values, or `undef` if the key does not exist.

This is based on the general rule of a hash slice:

```
%foo = ( a => 1, b => 2, c => 3 );
print @foo{'a','b'};               # prints 12
%bar = ( foo => \%foo );           # foo is now a reference in %bar
print @{ $bar{foo} }{'a','b'};     # prints 12, same data as before
```

Answer (score 4):

First, when you expect to get a list from a hash slice, use `@` sigil first. `%` is pointless here.

Second, you should understand that `$hash{$document}` value is not a hash or array. It's a reference - to a hash OR to an array.

With all this said, you might use something like this:

```
@{ $hash{$document} }{ @list };
```

... so you dereference value of `$hash{$document}`, then use a hash slice over it. For example:

```
my %hash = (
    'one' => {
        'first'  => 1,
        'second' => 2,
     },
     'two' => {
        'third'  => 3,
        'fourth' => 4,
     } 
);

my $key  = 'one';
my @list = ('first', 'second');

print $_, "\n" for @{ $hash{$key} }{@list};
# ...gives 1\n2\n
```